# Can I use NODE_ENV="staging" with mode="production" in webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

My app use NODE_ENV for deciding which api server should request to.

```
NODE_ENV="production" => https://api.***/
NODE_ENV="staging" => https://api.staging-***/
NODE_ENV="development" => http://localhost:3000/
```

I want to build staging bundle with mode="production" but keep NODE_ENV="staging".

I try to build with config below, but bundle.js becomes NODE_ENV="production".

```
{
   mode: "production",
   plugins: [
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       'process.env': {
         'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify("staging")
       }
     })
   ]
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webpack-cli is being deprecated and the syntax with env won't work anymore with Webpack-command (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-command#the---env-flag-is-nuked).

To satisfy your requirement I would use a simple env variable and use it the standard node way

```
var API_URL = {
  production: JSON.stringify('https://foo.bar/api'),
  development: JSON.stringify('http://localhost:3000/api'),
  staging: JSON.stringify('http://foo.stage.bar/api')
}

module.exports = function(argv) {
  const TARGET = process.env.TARGET_ENV ? process.env.TARGET_ENV : 'development';
  return {
    mode: argv.mode ? argv.mode : 'development',
....
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'API_URL': API_URL[TARGET]
    }),
....
}
```

and call webpack like this:

```
TARGET_ENV=staging webpack
```

In this way you would find your env variable API_URL defined globally in the app.

I would avoid redefining NODE_ENV through the define plugin.

Comment: very helpful link about `--env`! Thank you. I ultimately ended up defining the environment variable as you said along with the `EnvironmentPlugin` (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/). worked very well :)

Comment: Probably worth noting that `webpack-command` is now what's deprecated, not `webpack-cli`. The `--env` flag is still a thing, but it looks like you can also still do what's outlined in this answer. https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#cli-environment-variables

Answer (score 17):

I think that you want your staging build to be optimized just like your production build. And as far as I know some libraries (like *React*) will check if `NODE_ENV === "production"` to drop some error handling or provide further optimizations. So if you set `NODE_ENV` to `staging` they will "think" it's a development environment.

In this case, what I would do is just use a different variable like:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --env.TARGET_ENV=development",
  "staging": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --env.TARGET_ENV=staging",
  "production": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --env.TARGET_ENV=production"
},
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = (env) => {
  const mode = env.TARGET_ENV === 'development' ? 'development' : 'production';

  return {
    mode: mode,
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          'TARGET_ENV': JSON.stringify(env.TARGET_ENV)
        }
      })
    ]
    // ...rest of config based on environment
  };
};
```

Comment: How could we make sure TARGET_ENV is accessible at runtime though ?

Comment: I did the exact same setup but when I tried to execute 'npm run staging' I got this error from Webpack CLI "Error: Unknown option '--env.TARGET_ENV=staging'"